# How do I have my windows phone app run a timer in the background?

Tags: c#, timer, windows-10, win-universal-app

I'm trying to create an interval timer app as a learning project for windows 10 universal -- primarily for the phone. I think one of the things it's going to need to be able to do is continue running in the background or else there could be all kinds of really bad user experience when actually trying to use the app (e.g. running while playing music, using your phone while using the timer for cooking, etc). While trying to research how to do this on MSDN, I'm having a hard time finding the solution or even anything that would lead me to believe this is even possible. It appears that background services are only allowed to react to certain system events or run every 30 minutes, and apparently this was true with windows phone 8.1 as well -- I feel like I'm missing something because surely this can't be true! I understand that from a consumer point of view, having N number of background services running could do a number on performance and battery life, but not being able to do it seems incredibly limiting -- in that it could block me from building even a simple timer app.

Is this even possible? If so, how; can you point me in the right direction? If not, is there an alternative route I could look into? Looking for guidance.

NOTE:
I keep getting down-voted, claiming that background services are a clear topic in the documentation, but this is not true. Those background services run on intervals or in response to specific system events. I am asking about a background service *continues* to run even while the app is suspended. For example, if I have an interval timer map that needs to make a sound as each unique interval lapses. For this to be useful without have needing the phone unlocked, screen on, and app in the foreground, this would have to run in the background at least until the complete time has elapsed.

Comment: I found these two (among others) which might be helpful: [Create and register a background task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299100.aspx) and [BackgroundTask Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundTask)

Comment: Thanks for the input, I learned some *other* things, but one them repeats what I said about only reacting to system events, and the other (which I found somewhat helpful) seems to imply that it can only wake up as frequently as every minute to do whatever which I'm not sure is very useful. Again, I basically need to be able to transfer my timer to a background worker so that it can keep running when the main app isn't in focus. I keep getting downvoted (on other sites as well) because I'm being accused of not reading these articles that talk about background services, which isn't the same.